# How can I specify android Instrumentation context when I run my ActivityTestRule test cases?

Tags: android-espresso, android-testing

I have one android system with two displays(Display1, display2) connected for my app. my app has an activity that is running on display2. I was trying to use android espresso library to test my activity on display2.

Below is my test code:

```
onView(withId(R.id.button_test)).check(matches(isDisplayed())); //This line worked fine, it means espresso found my view successfully.
onView(withId(R.id.button_test)).withFailureHandler(new FailureHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Throwable error, Matcher<View> viewMatcher){
            if(error != null){
            }
        }
    }).check(matches(isDisplayed())).perform(click());
```

I always got an exception:

> androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 78, 119 and precision: 16, 16'
>   on view 'MyDrawableView{id=2131361875, res-name=button_info, desc=Toggle, visibility=VISIBLE, width=64, height=64, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=true, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=true, layout-params=android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@f6fa020, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=47.0, y=88.0}'.

It seems the coordinates(78, 119) is located on Display1. I also checked ActivityTestRule source code and found that:

```
  instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
```

this instrumentation was using Display1 context to perform the click event. my question is that:
How should I specify instrumentation context? or if you have any better idea on this test.

Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: Try to check button id, where the id indicates. use ctrl + click on it.

Comment: Hi @RahulKhatri, this is a espresso test, I couldn't use ctrl + click to do anything, it's all automatic.
onView(withId(R.id.button_test)).check(matches(isDisplayed())); 
//This line worked fine, it means espresso found my view successfully.
I think the root cause is espresso initialize instrumentation with the display1, not display2. I think it should work if I can specify the context of instrumentation. unfortunately, I couldn't find it.

Comment: Ok for that try android test sample: https://github.com/android/testing-samples

Comment: Hi @RahulKhatri, thanks for response. Just tried the link you shared. the link contains all the espresso basic test cases, it is not the one I'm looking for. I need to test my activity on the secondary display(screen), not on only one display.

Comment: Hi! if you want to test for fragment try this: https://oneflare.io/android-how-to-test-ui-fragments-with-espresso/, or you want to test two activity like one click second activity open then try this: https://github.com/udacity/AdvancedAndroid_TeaTime/tree/TESP.02-Solution-AddMenuActivityScreenTest

Comment: Hi @RahulKhatri, As I said, I can test single Fragment or activity on display1, it worked like a charm. the issue I'm facing is I can NOT test my fragment or activity on my display2. Display1 is a device that running my activity1, Display2 is another device that running my activity2. I want to test activity2. Display1 and Display2 are connected to a motherboard that running android system.

Comment: This is beyond my knowledge please try it on Google support community: https://support.google.com/android/community?hl=en or Kotlin disscusion : https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/, same like stack you can get solution.

Comment: Thank you all the time for your help.